# Как правильно указать путь к файлу lang_rus.properties?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Помогите пожалуйста! На главной странице приложения я указал для одной из кнопкок text="%ruth_test_main" в fxml файле, теперь хочу подключить файл с русским языком. Как правильно указать путь к файлу lang_rus.properties ?

```
[![][1]][1]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Попробуйте "HealthHelper.lang.lang"

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите полное имя пакета "HealthHelper.lang.lang".

Советую посмотреть в сторону maven/gradle, они сами размечают структуру проекта и разделяют хранение java классов и всех остальных (ресурсных) файлов отдельно.

Это позволит в будущем не хардкодить имена пакетов, а цепляться к местоположению какого-либо из файлов Lang.class.getResource("Lang").

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]